# Web Deploy Parameters and TeamCity.

Tags: teamcity, webdeploy

I'm trying to setup CI with TeamCity and stuck in deployment stage. My goal is to avoid multiple builds on deploy to every environment, so I'm not using msbuild and trying to do it with msdeploy.

So I need to transform my web.config file with Parameters.xml file. Transformation is complex enough, that's not just changing value of one of the elements, I need to replace entire tag with another tag, for example all connectionStrings section with connectionStrings section from another file (Web.Dev.config).

My parameters.xml file looks like:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="Connection Strings" value="%teamcity.build.workingDir%\artifacts\Configs\B2B.Web\Web.Dev.config:://configuration/connectionStrings">
    <parameterEntry type="XMLFile" scope="B2B.Web\\web.config$" match="//configuration/connectionStrings"/>
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

I can't realize how can I get path to my teamcity artifacts. If I set absolute path all works fine:

```
<parameters>
   <parameter name="Connection Strings" value="C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e4249c2d6a4e9e8d\artifacts\Configs\Web.Dev.config:://configuration/connectionStrings">
       <parameterEntry type="XMLFile" scope="B2B.Web\\web.config$" match="//configuration/connectionStrings"/>
   </parameter>
</parameters>
```

But when I use relative path It doesn't work.

So my question is: what is a valid relative path to my web.dev.config file?
I use TeamCity so I can use some environment variables like %teamcity.build.workingDir%. But I still can't make it work.